# Selecting a single column from a tibble still returns a tibble instead of a vector

Tags: r, dataframe, tibble

I have a tibble called `df`:

```
> class(df)
[1] "tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame"
```

Now I run:

```
> sen <- df[df$my_dummy==0, "col_name"]
```

This returns another tibble:

```
> class(sen)
[1] "tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame"
```

Why?

How can I get a "numeric" out of it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try `pull`

```
sen <- df %>%
  filter(my_dummy == 0) %>%
  pull(col_name)
```

Comment: and How I do specify the column? There is a "col_name" also

Comment: @robertspierre If you want to filter by `my_dummy` and then select only `col_name` column, then simply by `pull(col_name)` to extract as numeric vector. I edit my code above.

Comment: @robertspierre Oh...I always forget to notice that. I'm really sorry.

Comment: `unlist(df[df$my_dummy==0, "col_name"])` should work, if you wanted to go without further `tidyverse` packages

Answer (score 1):

You can try `$` to extract the `col_name` as vector. Try -

```
sen <- df$col_name[df$my_dummy == 0]
```

Answer (score 1):

Tibbles are more restrictive (for type safety), as you can see in the vignette suggested by @user13032723.

For a comparison of the behaviour of tibbles and data.frames, see the outputs you get from the same subsetting operations over the two classes:

```
# A tibble: 9 x 2
  expressions                                     output                 
  <chr>                                           <chr>                  
1 iris['Sepal.Length'] %>% class                  data.frame             
2 iris[,'Sepal.Length'] %>% class                 numeric  ###              
3 iris[['Sepal.Length']] %>% class                numeric                
4 iris$Sepal.Length %>% class                     numeric                
5 iris %>% pull('Sepal.Length') %>% class         numeric                
6 tibble(iris)['Sepal.Length'] %>% class          tbl_df, tbl, data.frame
7 tibble(iris)[,'Sepal.Length'] %>% class         tbl_df, tbl, data.frame ###
8 tibble(iris)[['Sepal.Length']] %>% class        numeric                
9 tibble(iris) %>% pull('Sepal.Length') %>% class numeric
```

As you can see, tibbles handle subsetting differently. They do not simplify the object class by default with base subsetting (`[x,y]`). See the difference between rows `2` and `7`of the table (`###`).

To consistently extract vectors out of dataframes, you can use the `$`extractor, the double brackets `[[]]`, or `pull()`.

**Code**

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)

tibble(expressions=c("iris['Sepal.Length'] %>% class",
                     "iris[,'Sepal.Length'] %>% class",
                     "iris[['Sepal.Length']] %>% class",
                     "iris$Sepal.Length %>% class",
                     "iris %>% pull('Sepal.Length') %>% class",
                     "tibble(iris)['Sepal.Length'] %>% class",
                     "tibble(iris)[,'Sepal.Length'] %>% class",
                     "tibble(iris)[['Sepal.Length']] %>% class",
                     "tibble(iris) %>% pull('Sepal.Length') %>% class"))%>%
        mutate(output=map_chr(expressions, ~eval(parse(text=.x))%>%
                                  toString))
```

Answer (score 0):

And answering: why?

This is a conscious decision. You can read about this in the vignette: [Tibbles](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tibble/vignettes/tibble.html).

Being "strict" is mentioned there. I you have a data.frame, by default argument `drop` is set to `TRUE`, but it doesn't mean that in any situation data.frame will be dropped and you will get vector. See this example:

```
df <- data.frame(a = 1, b = 2, c = 3)

var <- "a"

df[, var] # numeric vector

var <- c("a", "b")

df[, var] # data.frame
```

var can change and thus behavior of data.frame can change. This change of behavior (which depends on something you can't predict) is a reason.

Comment: Yes but by "var" is on your first case (just one column) not the second one