# Extracting single row from data.frame without loss of names

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I am simply extracting a single row from a `data.frame`. Consider for example

```
d=data.frame(a=1:3,b=1:3)
d[1,]    # returns a data.frame
#   a b
# 1 1 1
```

The output matched my expectation. The result was not as I expected though when dealing with a `data.frame` that contains a single column.

```
d=data.frame(a=1:3)
d[1,]   # returns an integer
# [1] 1
```

Indeed, here, the extracted data is not a `data.frame` anymore but an `integer`! To me, it seems a little strange that the same function on the same data type wants to return different data types. One of the issue with this conversion is the loss of the column name.

To solve the issue, I did

```
extractRow = function(d,index)
{
    if (ncol(d) > 1)
    {
        return(d[index,])
    } else
    {
        d2 = as.data.frame(d[index,])
        names(d2) = names(d)
        return(d2)
    }
}

d=data.frame(a=1:3,b=1:3)
extractRow(d,1)
#   a b    
# 1 1 1

d=data.frame(a=1:3)
extractRow(d,1)
#   a
# 1 1
```

But it seems unnecessarily cumbersome. Is there a better solution?

Comment: This may illustrate the subject: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69084753/selecting-a-single-column-from-a-tibble-still-returns-a-tibble-instead-of-a-vect/69087492#69087492

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just subset with the `drop = FALSE` option:

```r
extractRow = function(d, index) {
    return(d[index, , drop=FALSE])
}
```

Comment: While this works It prints a warning that drop will be ignored (which isn't even true). `return(d[index, , drop=FALSE])` prevents this warning.

Comment: @RobinGertenbach Not sure what to make of your comment, as the code in the comment matches my answer already.

Comment: My comment uses two commas

Answer (score 2):

R tries to simplify data.frame cuts by default, the same thing happens with columns:

```
d[, "a"]

# [1] 1 2 3
```

Alternatives are:

- `d[1, , drop = FALSE]`
- `tibble::tibble` which has `drop = FALSE` by default

Answer (score 1):

I can't tell you why that happens - it seems weird. One workaround would be to use `slice` from `dplyr` (although using a library seems unecessary for such a simple task).

```
library(dplyr)
slice(d, 1)
```

```
  a
1 1
```

Answer (score 0):

data.frames will simplify to vectors or scallars whith base subsetting `[,]`.

If you want to avoid that, you can use tibbles instead:

```
> tibble(a=1:2)[1,]

# A tibble: 1 x 1
      a
  <int>
1     1

tibble(a=1:2)[1,] %>% class
[1] "tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame"
```